# How can I use org-mode to export html with TOC (table-of-content) when body-only is t?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use org-mode to export the content of a blog, then use jekyll to produce the result blog page.

I found that when I set the **body-only** to true, the org-project export does not contain the **TOC**(table of content) of the org file.

How can I config to let emacs produce the TOC?

Here is my `.emacs` configuration:

```
;; org-mode project define                                                                                                            
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(
        ("org-blog-content"
         ;; Path to your org files.                                                                                                   
         :base-directory "~/ChinaXing.org/org/"
         :base-extension "org"

         ;; Path to your jekyll project.                                                                                              
         :publishing-directory "~/ChinaXing.org/jekyll/"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html
         :headline-levels 4
         :html-extension "html"
         :table-of-contents t
         :body-only t ;; Only export section between <body></body>                                                                    
         )

        ("org-blog-static"
         :base-directory "~/ChinaXing.org/org/"
         :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf\\|php"
         :publishing-directory "~/ChinaXing.org/jekyll/"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-publish-attachment)
        ("blog" :components ("org-blog-content" "org-blog-static"))
        ))
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-09/msg00599.html) post to the org-mode email list, the...

> [...] HTML exporter will refuse to include a TOC if body-only is t;
>   the atom exporter and a "send HTML messages with Wanderlust" hack
>   relied on that behaviour, which is why this was not changed in the
>   official Org repository.

One solution is to patch the source code of org-mode, as is done here:

http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/24227

Ian Barton apparently have implemented an alternative way to generate the TOC dynamically using jQuery. You may consider replying to [this](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/24227) thread post if you are interested in details about that solution.